# add lang to an existing Vuejs application

Tags: vue.js, internationalization

started studying VueJs. Wondering how to add the internationalization.  Consulted [this VueJs documentation page](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/internationalization/#getting-started):

> **Getting started**
>   To set the available locales or the current locale, supply the `lang` option when installing Vuetify.

Ask myself if everybody who starts learning VueJs think about internationalization...

My question it is there a way to add the `lang` option AFTER the vuejs application is created.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [`vue-i18n`](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n) since it is easy to set up and flexible for future additions. In order to add it:

```
npm install vue-i18n
```

Then, add a new plugin:

```
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
Vue.use(VueI18n)
const messages = {   
  en: {     
    message: {       
      hello: 'hello'     
    }   
  },   
  fr: {     
   message: {       
     hello: 'Bonjour'     
   }   
  } 
}
export const i18n = new VueI18n({ locale: 'en', fallbackLocale: 'fr', messages });
```

After that you can import it in your `main.js` and add to it inside your `vue` instance.

```
import {i18n} from './plugins/i18n';
new Vue({i18n,...
```

Finally you can use it in your app:

```
<p>{{ $t("message.hello") }}</p>
```

I recommend searching more on the topic, there are plenty of resources on it.

Comment: I understand you recomendation. But do you have an idea about how to solve the OP?

Comment: yes, I created the application, now want to internationalize